# Slider won't look the same on WP as offline. What's interfering?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, slider

I downloaded a slider called 'ParallaxContentSlider' which I intended to use for my website. I customized it a bit offline where everything worked perfectly, however, when I upload it to WP it won't look the same at all. I know something is interfering with it but I cannot find what's the matter. Would anyone care to help me out with this? Thank you in advance.

Here's two screenshots showing how it looks on WP versus offline on my computer:

[image]

As you can see the top picture has the text and width all messed up.
This might be overcourse and kind of offtopic but I would like this to be responsive aswell IF possible.

A link to [my website](http://beautifiedbyelsa.se/);

Many thanks! Would you like a fiddle or something, that can be arranged I presume.

Comment: Most probably, your theme settings are different in the two installations. Check for a setting called "boxed layout". Most themes have it and that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. Unfortunately I could not find anything called boxed layout anywhere. I noticed however that if I remove and/or edit the div called "container", it resizes, however the whole page resizes. How do I target just that slider??

Comment: The slider itself has the id of `da-slider`, so you can use the `#da-slider` selector. However, its parents are the ones limiting it. What you need to do is right-click on it and choose "Inspect Element" in Chrome or Firefox. You'll than be able to explore up and down the DOM, change CSS on the fly and see the results. Don't forget to copy-paste your changes in your stylesheet or they'll be gone when you refresh or navigate.

Comment: I tried what you suggested already and found that if I remove the `div class="container"` line everything sizes a hundred percent across the screen, every. thing. I'm at a loss as I can't figure out how to edit just that specific slider selector.

Comment: What you need is to place your slider outside that container. Or set the container's width to 100% in your CSS and wrap everything else but the slider in a custom container, with a set width. Not trying to be harsh, but you lack understanding of basic CSS concepts. My personal belief is that with CSS it takes about 2 years of everyday practice to have an idea about how much you don't know. It's ok, we've all been there. You just need exercise. If you don't have this time at your disposal, you should probably hire someone for the job, until you learn.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your tip(s). I never said I knew CSS. I am trying to learn, therefore I'm asking, what would be the point to ask if I already knew the answer? I don't need to hire nobody as the site is for my own business so it doesn't really matter. If you don't want to help me then please don't bother writing at all. I appreciate your tips and all, but I don't like elitists who think they know everything just because they've studied something longer than someone else.